# Лопатин дает ответ?

Tags: определения

1. Наблюдались единичные(,) крупные (,) неправильной формы (?) образования, возвышающиеся над поверхностью.
2. При воздействии... отмечалось образование фаций(,) округлой формы, бедных структурными элементами.

Согласно Лопатину, несогласованные определения обособляются:

2) если включаются в ряды однородных членов вместе с согласованными определениями (определяемое слово в таком случае может и не иметь впереди стоящего определения): Художник, ростом невысокий, юношески легкий вопреки своему росту, в берете и бархатной куртке, прошелся из угла в угол (Бун.).

Но из этого не могу сделать вывод относительно расстановки запятых в приведенных выше предложениях.

Какие здесь возможны варианты и на какие нормы ссылаться?

Определения *единичные* и *крупные*, должно быть, неоднородные. Поэтому запятая между ними не нужна. А нужно ли обособлять несогласованное определение *неправильной формы*? И если нужно (или не нужно), то почему?

*При воздействии... отмечалось образование фаций(,) округлой формы, бедных структурными элементами.*

Нужна ли здесь запятая в скобках и почему? Или не нужна? И на какую норму можно сослаться?

Answer (score 3):

(1) Наблюдались единичные, крупные, неправильной формы  образования, возвышающиеся над поверхностью.

(2) При воздействии... отмечалось образование фаций округлой формы, бедных структурными элементами.

Согласно Лопатину очень трудно решать такие задачи, они решаются по смыслу, часто в авторском варианте.

В предложении (1) перечислены признаки образования, с помощью которых описывается структура поверхности, здесь однородные отношения (ряд признаков изображает общую картину).

В предложении (2) первое определение не обособляется, так как обозначает отличительный признак существительного "фация", второе определение уточняет структуру образования.

Для справок. Фация - Пласт осадочной горной породы, отличающийся одинаковым составом, физико-химическими свойствами и заключающий в себе одинаковую ископаемую фауну и флору.

Comment: А относится ли "единичные" к свойствам образований, наблюдаемых на поверхности? Они встречаются и потому наблюдаются порознь, и уже "крупные, неправильной формы" относится к каждому из наблюдаемых одиночных образований. Я бы не поставил первую запятую. По крайней мере, если программой исследования поверхности в какой-нибудь заполняемый шаблон не заложены условные характеристики ожидаемых образований (единичные/множественные, крупные/мелкие и т.п.).

Comment: Всё зависит от текста. Если вы описываете местность (или среду), то все признаки можно считать однородными  (они в этом случае не одинаковые, а сближенные по смыслу, раскрывают общую тему)..

Comment: ЕДИНИЧНЫЙ, .1.  Крайне редкий (их мало) , 2. обособленный (они разбросаны, не скапливаются группами). В первом значении запятую можно не ставить (единичные, отдельные, в небольшом количестве), а во втором надо ставить, так как это характеристика структуры.

Answer (score 3):

```
  Какие здесь возможны варианты и на какие нормы ссылаться?
```

В первом примере варианты есть.  Alex_ander  совершенно верно предположил, что  "единичные"может быть общим для прилагательных "крупные, неправильной формы" и первую запятую можно не ставить: Наблюдались единичные крупные, неправильной формы образования, возвышающиеся над поверхностью.

Только речь здесь идёт не о геологии, я нашла исходный материал:
[Наблюдались единичные...](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=737.2Q8rm4KL9bijAfMimxDVSzGAAfzh78j_sIi3Iko2QHBMbunclaPf1xmy9Wxczip2Ouy0v5I30nK8em6tDliRSyoT-WJncnPXSMym7ADCh0Zj-Hd7_XXpXQ9AiXmYxk0JRuCYOsbYmSBxIWgwcmWVt0hE8mlY96tg1rdEx5THrFxcYH6rdyJD8a0vDCjqTh8K0JhfDEq5APG6HdBJHJ9AdazWVC9keEY0OBX9Wg1U1LyZt_Hxn-fu1kIinecuelqcOPT90zHKFLx5Jx_nrvC9Rt8mAwku-jJuatgm5enCcXA.b327cb5228d6ec83be32b9790a8b325142049ab5&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9T6U0-imFY5IWwl6BSUGTYmzqOeTLpgtuNwwv21bzymu2FZ93wygGmE&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxZ2Vna3QtendZOTRfc0M1bjdPazA5RnJUTEhieDJGUnRPbS13c29sVmpkeWlBWTY3MUIwbDZMdW9RMUFfYTE5WjZmSHUwTlJuMnZNVlF5cWFQS1Y1d2w1X0JCMTBEbnVKMFBmeWpwUmlMRlEwWFFoeGExMUcteHFpOGlMUmJMN1BkUjZ1NFVDMEpqLQ&b64e=2&sign=efb1d4adaf39b1840baebb1cd6562bf6&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQSaYtyyri96FiDw7n41FHW0K1ah0HW_pdKrItT9ny4CQUcGWDmY2HBw7VlUOlEBXbtsGn2AY1UAviXJc4A0TUCXsmff6-AVGQ0YRsrTaVfwYAuaBciwtV4Pbc04AmNF4QFCKVcVnBz143GgAMHEKmYL3NZ4LGboLVYKQYNtLOupg&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3mdB1NJZzO2O7AbhCEb2doUMzaL3e88fA3GfWmxfEw1q7-gQJDBw8C6An5Z_7TrGx1TvZilxRZL2CitynRFg-bwuas-tZUnL8ytvRuaQcCn02LmmFJRNH1j74Sd1s67ubhSBRx84jzXyZsjCG6ekFoU2FCHLn5ifeSgVJQPwVzE3dDLgng-pAcnCsmkL6Anzkwq0IjLah8xSQlJqobe818TiXdqIAK5sGh-yGKilSSuFXjuedXlpwyXbJhSGh8ZXWGuvjE24VSToqM2TWgN1lZkRp8YtJP8vpXf8gim9xfehSnGIqSLGNvPIiWImqjmD3J5-I8yAM0is27brRFNna1-nQ2m3jnQa0AEMYPqDRleGq6p9yEY7nYVNAYGJQp-UUgDfMqRIRpxWCS9YQssjNCIlThGIhhEYEXU_ISm-re5nI5UjDK3su8ZLtILuyiAn7twKJPpvDv44h42KfcZfdhJqa2ybhqt4Hxm98UvvoJwY3BNjki2yVIqdUdB8tFDEPdfNBM1JPEOwqL44ogmvSDRFPYxmINGFDEGDT8RHNbdKa58ycdWMHfibvikPnb43Ns2lhQhZ4dssG-MifNE9ErU3UivINbmgwqNTK0oK0_BHhCjbu6nL5frYTmFqwX9i8j7rayF92FqlyJOh-mTJMCzbqbYWjIXeXELCAyVizDQBhYiCHKh3LE4kO0lKGW6YjwZ5umLlRH8Rxr3epxQ_vMjUandzBrVfm7hwJT5QbRG8z61U6grn9wCd2s3ApNsQ3A&l10n=ru&cts=1435842961801&mc=3.4225797618424916)

Это медицинский текст, исследуется кровь.С помощью специального приема дегидратации капли биологической жидкости получают сухую структурированную пленку «фацию», которая представляет собой фиксированный тонкий «срез» исследуемой жидкости, здесь плазмы крови.

Вот текст: 
При клиновидной дегидратации водной суспензии ЛПС в наших условиях эксперимента отмечалось **образование фаций округлой формы**, бедных структурными элементами. Здесь хорошо визуализировались две зоны... Структура центральной зоны в большинстве фаций была однородной. Изредка здесь отмечались **единичные, крупные, неправильной формы образования, возвышающиеся над поверхностью фации.**

По смыслу текста идёт характеристика образований в виде перечисления качеств (в научных текстах это часто бывает), поэтому все качества здесь  можно перечислить через запятую, невзирая на разные свойства,- как однородные члены, они однородны в ряду качеств вообще.

Чего не скажешь о втором примере. При воздействии... отмечалось образование фаций округлой формы, бедных структурными элементами.Препозиция несогласованного определения по отношению к согласованному  говорит о ненужности запятой. Вот если бы было сначала согласованное: "...отмечалось образование фаций, бедных структурными элементами, округлой формы", - тогда запятая была бы нужна, ведь согласованное РАСПРОСТРАНЁННОЕ определение после определяемого слова нужно обособить.  Здесь вариантов нет. Иначе получится странный смысл: отмечалось образование фаций - они, фации, по-любому образуются, только смотря какие, как, например:это был человек крупного телосложения,похожий на...Попробуйте поставить запятую после "человек"...Мы ж не сомневаемся, что это человек, вот и там смысл, не в том, что образовались фации, а в том, какие они.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: Наблюдались единичные, крупные, неправильной формы образования, возвышающиеся над поверхностью.
При воздействии... отмечалось образование фаций округлой формы, бедных структурными элементами.

В первом предложении запятая разделяет однородные определения. Здесь "единичные и крупные" характеризуют предмет с разных сторон: указывается размер и форма.

Во втором примере нет никаких оснований отрывать определение от определяемого слова. 
 Важным критерием обособления Н/о, являются следующие факторы:

> если определение относятся к собственному имени лица.
>   относятся к названиям лиц по степени родства, занимаемому положению, профессии и т. д.
>
> относятся к личному местоимению
>
> отделены от определяемого слова другими членами предложения (независимо от >того, выражено ли определяемое слово именем собственным или нарицательным)
>
> если образуют ряд однородных членов предложения с предшествующими/последующими обособленными согласованными определениями (независимо от того, какой частью речи выражено определяемое слово)
>
> имеет место намеренный отрыв определительного оборота от соседнего сказуемого, к которому он мог бы быть отнесен по смыслу и синтаксически, и отнесение его к подлежащему

Таком образом, если обособить определение в этом примере, нарушится связь между определяемым словом и определением.